# Import contacts from vcf file to Windows 7.5 Mango

Tags: contacts, 7.x, transfer, android

I just got a new Windows (7.5) Phone. I exported *all* contacts from my old Android phone to a vcf file but have no idea how to import it to my Windows phone. Any ideas? Are there other ways to transfer contact lists from Android to Windows phones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to convert the file to a `.csv` file first if you plan to upload it online, this depends from service to service. It's required for Windows Live on my first look. Try http://labs.brotherli.ch/vcfconvert/ or search an off-line variant.

In case you have Windows Live:

1. Go to http://live.com/ and log into your Windows Live.
2. On the Inbox page, click Messenger at the top and then click Contacts.
3. Click on Import, then on Outlook and then upload your `.csv` file.

In case you have Gmail:

1. Go to http://gmail.com/ and log into your Gmail.
2. Click on Contacts at the top-left corner.
3. Click the More Actions button above the list of contacts, then click Import.
4. You should be able to upload a `.vcf` file here, follow the instructions further.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Importing the vcf into gmail worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 5):

Since you had an Android phone before, I guess you might have synced all your contacts to your gmail account. Add your gmail account to Windows phone, and set sync options to include contacts. All your contacts are automatically synced. (even without the vcf files.)

Comment: In my Windows phone not all contacts I had in my Android are present. What's the foolproof way to get all contacts aside from gmail syncing?

Comment: @prrao: It's either syncing or inserting them manually, I doubt if there is an application that can do this for you and otherwise you would have to write a software solution which could be considered overkill. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have set up a live account linked to the phone, can you not import the contacts from the vcf into live on a PC and then it will sync from there to the phone?

I've got 2 hotmail accounts, exchange account, facebook, twitter and linkedin all set up on the phone with all contacts syncing and linking correctly.

Comment: I'm new to Windows phones, so if I understand correctly, I can connect my *Windows* phone to my PC and it will give me an option to sync with the vcf?

Comment: Not quite, you can either set up gmail sync as described by franklins, or if you import the contacts directly into the live account that you set up your phone with, then it will sync from there. Its the same solution but a different provider.